# Speech Recognition/Identification

Tags: c#

What am I up against if I want to do comparisons in voices? I have an audio source that I want to track who's talking based on their voice (voice pattern?) - are there any C# libraries to get me close?

Comment: Hi, It's called Speaker diarisation,while before you go that far you need to know Voice Activity Detection. After that search for online/offline speaker diaristion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer was what Du Sijun stated in a reply.

> Hi, It's called Speaker diarisation,while before you go that far you need to know Voice Activity Detection. After that search for online/offline speaker diaristion. – Du Sijun Feb 4 at 6:35